# react-native: Image style gave an error with typescript (expo)

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, react-native, expo

I working on an application using expo (react-native) with typescript and UI-kitten.

this error pops up when trying to pass style prop to Image component and I don't know why or how to fix it:

code:

```
<Image style={styles.storeImage} source={{ uri: image }} />
       ^^^^^
// the error happened here:
<Image
   style={styles.modalImage}
   ^^^^^
// and here
   source={require("../assets/Preview.jpeg")}
/>

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  modalImage: {
    width: 315,
    height: 255,
    marginVertical: 10,
    borderWidth: 3,
    borderRadius: 20,
  },
storeImage: {
    borderRadius: 4,
    width: "100%",
    height: "100%",
  },
})
```

simply erery time I want to pass the style prop to the image component this error showed up.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine for me. Are you importing Image from "react-native" or from other place?

Comment: I don't know, I imported Image form react-native `import { Image } from "react-native";` the code compiled and work fine but the error always pops up in VS-code

Comment: If you write this (instead of using the stylesheet), does it work? <Image
   style={{width: 315,
    height: 255,
    marginVertical: 10,
    borderWidth: 3,
    borderRadius: 20}}
   source={require("../assets/Preview.jpeg")}
/>

Comment: yeah it works the error disapeared